# How to set a Yii2 module to return JSON response using config/main.php

Tags: json, configuration, module, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am currently using the following lines of code on every controller in the API module in order to return JSON response/data.

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats']['text/html'] =  Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return $behaviors;
    }
```

It works well. But how can i achieve the same using main configuration file?
I tried the following on my frontend/config/main.php

```
    'api' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\api\Module',
        'components' => [
          'user' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\User',
                    'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
                    'enableSession' => false,
                    'loginUrl' => null,
                    ],

          'response' => [
                   'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
                   'formats' => [
                        'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                                ],
                    ]
        ],// Module component

    ],
```

above configuration still returns XML response only.  What is the correct configuration to set all the controllers in the API module to return JSON data.Thanks

Comment: Try accessing the api via Postman. It must return JSON data

Answer (score 2):

Configure your response component as follows:

```
'response' => [
    'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    // ...
]
```

`formats` is an array containing the available formats. `format` is the actual output format.

Comment: Source: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html
See the description before Public Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Add this is your config/main-local.php

```
use yii\web\Response;
$config['bootstrap'][]=
    [
        'class' => '\yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
        'formats' => [

            'text/html' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: Your solution is working but globally. How to apply the same to a particular module? Thanks

Comment: you can attach Behaviors to Module or extend your controllers to a base controller

Comment: Later but not never :) Please use \Yii::$app->response->format = \Yii\web\Response:: FORMAT_JSON;